# Unable to parse JSON file using GSON library

Tags: java, json, gson

I am unable to parse this JSON file.
Any suggestions are appreciated. I have created POJO classes from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ I tried JSON deserilization solution mentioned but it did not work out for me.

```
    {
  "error": "",
  "data": [
    {
      "view": "Viewpapger",
      "data": [
        {
          "view": "ImageView",
          "data": {
            "url": "random.jpg"
          },
          "properties": {
            "width": "fill_parent",
            "height": "500"
          }
        },
        {
          "view": "Textview",
          "data": {
            "text": "afvnjkafvf"
          },
          "properties": {
            "width": "fill_parent"
          }
        },
        {
          "view": "Textview",
          "data": {
            "text": "afvnjkafvf"
          },
          "properties": {
            "width": "fill_parent"
          }
        },
        {
          "view": "ImageView",
          "data": {
            "url": "random.jpg"
          },
          "properties": {
            "width": "fill_parent",
            "height": "500"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "width": "wrap_content",
        "height": "500"
      }
    },
    {
      "view": "Textview",
      "data": {
        "text": "afvnjkafvf"
      },
      "properties": {
        "width": "fill_parent"
      }
    },
    {
      "view": "ImageView",
      "data": {
        "url": "random.jpg"
      },
      "properties": {
        "width": "fill_parent",
        "height": "500"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not getting how to setup the model classes for this

Comment: Take a hint from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ select json and Gson as library.

Comment: Yes i tried that, its a handy tool for normal json file but my json looks bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the JSON structure does not correspond to any strictly specified schema but seems more like an ad-hoc collection of keys and values. For example, (it seems that) depending on the value of the `view` field in your view description object the `data` field can be either

- a JSON array containing other view descriptions (for "Viewpager")
- a JSON object containing a string called "url" (for "ImageView")
- a JSON object containing a string called "text" (for "TextView")

So, basically it seems that `data` can be *anything* and moreover that you could have an arbitrarily deep tree of nodes where `data` could be anything at any level in the tree. (It may be different though if, for example, you can always be certain that the top level element is a "Viewpager" that contains one level of sub-views like "ImageView" or "TextView" - if you have any guarantees like that let me know).

In that case I think you are better off parsing the JSON in some other, less strict way (maybe using `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONObject`) and then handling all the different cases "manually".